# Fixed elements scroll when focus goes to input element in mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

I have noticed, that by default, the whole page will scroll up (even fixed elements such as a header) when focusing on an input element (or similar) that would be obscured by the on-screen keyboard. It is possible (albeit ugly) to scroll back up using this snippet:

```
$('textarea, input').bind('focusin focus',function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('html, body').animate({scrollTop:0,scrollLeft:0}, 'slow'); 
});
```

Still, if the user then scrolls manually, he scrolls the whole document including fixed elements (the header).

A dirty fix would be to add some empty lines to some main div containing the form (which should be scrolling if needed). Then even with the keyboard out, the user can now only manually scroll the main div, not the whole document.

Is there a better solution?

Like specifying a "should scroll if needed" div?

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

It is not because the viewport changes, I was wronge there.

The browser automatically scrolls the page, so that the keyboad is not overlapping over the input field that is currently focused.

Comment: Why does the behavior change depending on whether the div containing the form is scrollable or not?

Comment: I was wrong with my first answer, I just tested it. The viewport does not change. please check my updated answer

Comment: Yes, you restated my observation. It is however not an answer to my question.